# Merge rows with same value in csv file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a csv file like below

```
a,123,xyz
a,345,zyx
b,123,xyz
b,345,zyx
```

I would like to merge the first column with same value in the row. like below

```
a,123,xyz
  345,zyx
b,123,xyz
  345,zyx
```

I have sorted the file and tried to count the values but not able to proceed as I need to do in shell script

Comment: can you share some of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the desired output with the following awk snippet:

```
awk -F, '{ if (f == $1) { for (c=0; c <length($1) + length(FS); c++) printf " "; print $2 FS $3 } else { print $0 } } { f = $1 }' FILE
```

Or just the awk program formatted:

```
{
    if (f == $1) {
        for (c=0; c < length($1) + length(FS); c++)
            printf " "
        print $2 FS $3
    } else {
        print $0
    }
}

{
    f = $1
}
```

Explanation:

If the first field (`$1`) matches the first field of the previous line (`f`, which is assigned at the end of processing each line with `f = $1`), then we print spaces for the length of the field to be omitted plus the length of the field separator (`FS`). Else, we just print the entire line (`$0`).

---

If the comma needs to be kept, the awk program should be this:

```
{
    if (f == $1) {
        for (c=0; c < length($1); c++)
            printf " "
        print FS $2 FS $3
    } else {
        print $0
    }
}

{
    f = $1
}
```

This will print:

```
a,123,xyz
 ,345,zyx
b,123,xyz
 ,345,zyx
```

Comment: Thank so much for your help. You are almost near to my requirement. After including your code I am getting the out put as below 

`a,123,xyz 
345,zyx 
b,123,xyz 
345,zyx`


It is removing the white spaces in the first column and replacing that with second column. Due to this the header mismatch is happening. Also, I am not able to show here but I would like to Merge two rows in the first column containing only value 'a' and another two rows with value 'b'. Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with all the details. Hard to understand your problem in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Philipe. I have updated below. can you please check and help me?

Comment: @SridharAdurthi, I meant a new question, not an answer :) In any case, the snippet I posted specifically prints the space in order to align the columns. Maybe you still need the comma. I'll update the answer to mention that. Note though that the original snippet for sure doesn't remove the space.

Comment: You know what I made a mistake due to that it is removing the ",". I realized and your code is working awesome now. Thank you so much. for merging the rows in the first column, you want me to go with a separate question for that?

Comment: Yes, that's a different question ;)

Comment: Thanks Philipe. I have raised a different question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060763/shell-to-merge-cells-in-csv-file

Comment: @Philipe, is that not possible to merge rows in a csv file using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
awk '$1==p{sub("[^,]*,",s)}
    {p=$1; s = sprintf("%"(1 + length(p))"s","")}1' FS=, OFS=, input
```

It's much simpler if you don't worry about the leading indentation:

```
awk '$1==p{sub("[^,]*,","")}{p=$1}1' FS=, OFS=, input
```